# How to get Jqgrid row data as array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jqgrid

I am populating JQGrid as `datatype: "local"`. Now i need to populate every row data in an array as shown below

```
 var aa = [1, 2, 3, 4];

 var rows = [];
 rows.push(['Nr.', 'Name', 'Beschreibung', 'Preis', 'Anzahl', 'MwSt(%)']);

 for (var i = 0; i <= aa.length; i++) {
 rows.push(['#.' + i, 'xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx']);
 }

 var dd = {
   content: {
    table: {
    widths: ['*', 100, 200, '*', '*', '*'],
    body: rows
 }
}
};
```

Now, i am trying to get the rows in the above shown format by below code

```
 var a = [];

 a = $('#dataGrid').jqGrid('getRowData');
```

but not able to format exactly as showed in sample format. What's wrong here? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a bit of a different approach might be helpful.  Here I have reworked your code to implement your example properly...

```
var aa = [1, 2, 3, 4];

//Headers for table
var headers = [
  { label: "Nr.", name: "nr", width: "100", key: true },
  { label: "Name", name: "name", width: "100" },
  { label: "Beschreibung", name: "beschreibung", width: "200" },
  { label: "Preis", name: "preis", width: "100" },
  { label: "Anzahl", name: "anzahl", width: "100" },
  { label: "MwSt(%)", name: "mwSt", width: "*" }
];

//Prefill with fake rows
var dataRows = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= aa.length; i++) {
  dataRows.push({
    nr: "#." + i,
    name: "xx",
    beschreibung: "xx",
    preis: "xx",
    anzahl: "xx",
    mwSt: "xx"
  });
}

var jqGridConfig = {
  datatype: "local",
  data: dataRows,
  colModel: headers
};

$("#dataGrid").jqGrid(jqGridConfig)
```

See the Pen [ZMdVyP](https://codepen.io/peterpde/pen/ZMdVyP/) by Peter Edwards ([@peterpde](https://codepen.io/peterpde)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).